# Objective complement?

Tags: infinitives, predicative-complements, diagramming

When diagramming "You heard me sing," would you form a clause as the direct object, with me as the subject of the verb sing (even though me is an objective pronoun)? Or, would you think of sing as an infinitive (to sing) modifying me?

Comment: _Sing_ is a _to_-less infinitive, and the subject of an infinitive is the base (objective) form of a pronoun, like _me, him, her, us, them_. There is no difference with nouns, of course.

Answer (score 1):

*You heard me [sing*].

"Hear" is a catenative verb, and "sing" is an infinitival subordinate clause functioning as its catenative complement.

"Me" is the syntactic object of "hear", and the *semantic* subject of the subordinate clause.